# Good approach for hundreds of comsumers and big files

Tags: c#, .net, performance, multithreading, dataflow

I have several files (nearly 1GB each) with data. Data is a string line.

I need to process each of these files with several hundreds of consumers. Each of these consumers does some processing that differs from others. Consumers do not write anywhere concurrently. They only need input string. After processing they update their local buffers. Consumers can easily be executed in parallel.

Important: With one specific file each consumer has to process all lines (without skipping) in correct order (as they appear in file). The order of processing different files doesn't matter.

Processing of a single line by one consumer is comparably fast. I expect less than 50 microseconds on Corei5.

So now I'm looking for the good approach to this problem.
This is going to be be a part of a .NET project, so please let's stick with .NET only (C# is preferable).

I know about TPL and DataFlow. I guess that the most relevant would be `BroadcastBlock`. But i think that the problem here is that with each line I'll have to wait for all consumers to finish in order to post the new one. I guess that it would be not very efficient.

I think that ideally situation would be something like this:

1. One thread reads from file and writes to the buffer.
2. Each consumer, when it is ready, reads the line from the buffer concurrently and processes it.
3. The entry from the buffer shouldn't be deleted as one consumer reads it. It can be deleted only when all consumers have processed it.
4. TPL schedules consumer threads itself.
5. If one consumer outperforms the others, it shouldn't wait and can read more recent entries from the buffer.

Am i right with this kind of approach? Whether yes or not, how can i implement the good solution?

I was suggested to move the question here as more appropriate place from StackOverflow.

**Update:**
According to david.pfx comment here is some detailing. Performance is at the first place, ease of maintenance is at the second.

Comment: The question is whether you are writing this code for ease of implementation, for ease of maintenance, for maximum performance or for some other reason. Please edit your question to provide additional info and constraints on the required solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different channel on a message queue for each consumer.  For each line in one of your big files write a message to each channel (e.g. each consumer).  Each consumer can process messages on its channel deleting the messages once received.

Comment: Do you mean MessageQueue class? Why not just ConcurrentQueue buffer?

Comment: I mean an [actual message queue](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732184.aspx) as supported by [message queuing software](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx).